# osx Drag not working

Tags: macos, swift, drag-and-drop

i wanted to create a minimal working example of Drag operations using swift. However, this is not working well so far. None of the NSDraggingDestination functions is called, but I can't spot my error :(

```
class DragView : NSView , NSDraggingDestination {


required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    println("init")
    super.init(coder: coder)
    let theArray = NSImage.imageFileTypes()
    self.registerForDraggedTypes(theArray)
}

override func draggingEntered(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
    println("draggingEntered")
    return NSDragOperation.Copy
}


override func draggingUpdated(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> NSDragOperation {
    println("draggingUpdated")
    return NSDragOperation.Copy
}

override func prepareForDragOperation(sender: NSDraggingInfo) -> Bool {
    println("prepareForDragOperation")
    return true
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSImage.imageFileTypes()` is not a valid array for `self.registerForDraggedTypes`.

Try with `[NSFilenamesPboardType]` for example.

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    println("init")
    super.init(coder: coder)
    self.registerForDraggedTypes([NSFilenamesPboardType])
}
```